# Set order / weight of user profile core fields against user profile custom fields

Tags: 7, entities

Is it possible to set the order of core fields against custom fields added on user profile page?
I want to bring the status field to the bottom of the list.
I'm trying the code below but without succes:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['status']['#weight'] = 100;
}
```

I want something in the following order for example:

- Username (core)
- Password (core)
- Custom field 1
- Custom field 2
- Status
  (core)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can just try and set the weight as follows

```
$form['status']['#weight'] = field_info_max_weight('user', 'user', 'form') + 10;
```

Have not tried it but I am pretty sure it will work. This will make sure the status will always be the last field.

Also it should be `$form['account']['status']['#weight']`

Comment: Awesome, never even heard of that function before but it's very heplful

Comment: Ya I came across it from the fields ui module when I was working on a project which created dynamic fields and I was looking for something like that. There is even a hook for that function.

Comment: Yeah so it does, thanks; I'd up-vote again if I could :)

Comment: Ah i see that the status field is inside the account array. Actually what I intend to do is pull out this status field and set the weight of it according to the other custom fields one level up